# Has anyone ever done a comparison between SQL Server and Scimore?

Tags: sql-server, database, scimore

We are currently investigating using Scimore in place of SQL Server for one of our desktop applications.

The biggest reason is that installing SQL Server is a pain as part of a deployment since we cannot control the target desktop environment. This results in a ton of failed installations due to all kind of reasons.

So, Scimore is what we are looking at right now. Has anyone got any experience in it?

Comment: I have no experience with Scimore (never even heard of it before). Any reason you're not looking at SQL Server Compact Edition?

Comment: Too many problems installing it in different environments - and also the fact that we need server database as well in certain scenarios - Scimore has both in-process and out-of-process modes.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Compact Edition is a very nice product. Its mature and deeply integrated with developer studio. But its restricted:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx

Scimore has its advantages too.

- exactly as you write, then different usage models - in process/out of process/service/distributed.
- no restrictions in terms of cpu usages, database sizes, features...
- easy deployment, just bundle dll's (<5Mb)